# GIS/Geospatial Podcast

Tags: references

I wanted to know if there are any free available to download informative GIS/Geospatial audio or video podcast other than [ESRI Instructional Series Podcasts](http://www.esri.com/news/podcasts/instructional-series.html)  and [Speaker Series Podcasts](http://www.esri.com/news/podcasts/speaker-series.html) in the market. I am interested in general news/advancements in GIS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Very Spatial** (Excellent GIS Podcast resource)
http://veryspatial.com/avsp/

Yahoo GIS podcast pipe (multiple sources)
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=esYT7kD02xGnVcFEyzUFzw

iTunes - GIS & location tech
http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/gis-and-location-technology/id123042141

Answer (score 5):

[Directions Magazine](http://www.directionsmag.com/site/gsearch/?cx=partner-pub-5866307919792600:9iwg6wuxtt6&cof=FORID:11&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=podcast&sa.x=0&sa.y=0&sa=Search#1424) periodically has podcasts in this area, as well as articles, news, webinars, etc.  These are created or edited by very knowledgeable and experienced editors, [Joe Francica and Adena Shutzberg](http://www.directionsmag.com/info/about-us/), and their collaborators.